# Having trouble stretching image in ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

Here is my code for the ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/undoButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/undobutton_disabled"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chessBoard" />
```

Here is the result so far

[image]
This is what Ive tried so far:

```
1. Made the scaleType fitCenter, but that didn't work.

2. Made the imagebutton height and width the same size as my picture, but that didnt work either.
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm sorry, I JUST figured out the answer as soon as i posted this question.

```
android:padding="0dp"
```

That fixed my problem.

EDIT: Should I just delete this question?

Comment: Hi Clay No need to delete

Answer (score 1):

If you're wrapping your content, your `ImageView` will fit the actual size of your image.

You need to replace

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

with something else, e.g.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```